# wx.taskbaricon remain active even when modal window is open

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building wxpython (2.9.4) app that uses wx.taskbaricon. On OS X, when modal windows is open, taskbaricon become disabled, which is expected behaviour. Same program, on Win 7, task bar menu remain active even when I have modal windows open.

I simply want, on Win-7, to make taskbaricon disabled (the way it works on OS X) while any modal windows is open in my app.

Comment: Are you sure that Windows users are ready for disappearing taskbaricon ? Maybe icon doesn't disappear because most programs in Windows don't disable taskbaricon. I don't use Windows for long time so I'm not sure.

Comment: There was fudge in my post. I meant task bar menu which appears on clicking taskbar icon. On OS X, when modal window is visible, all the menu item of task bar menu become disabled. Same not happening on Win-7 in which task bar menu remain enabled letting user click on menu item leading to conflict with existing modal window.